# How to prove the inequality below?

Tags: inequality

> Prove and interpret geometrically for $n \leq 3$
> $$
> \sqrt{(a_1+b_1+\ldots + z_1)^2 + \ldots + (a_n+b_n+\ldots + z_n)^2}
> \leq
> \sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+\ldots + a_n^2} + \sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2+\ldots + b_n^2} \ldots + \sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2+\ldots + z_n^2}
> $$

[image: inequality]

I know the geometrical interpretation but have no idea how to prove it algebraically.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Pythagorean theorem ?

Comment: Got it. Thank you. @Santos

Answer (score 2):

Let $\vec A=a_1\vec i+ a_2 \vec j +a_3\vec k$, similarly $\vec B$, $\vec C$ apply vector inequality that
$$|\vec A+\vec B+ \vec C| \le |\vec A|+ |\vec B|+|\vec C|$$
$$\implies \sqrt{(a_1+b_1+c_1)^2+(a_2+b_2+c_2)^2+(a_3+b_3+c_3)^2}\le $$
$$\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}+\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2+b_2^2}+\sqrt{c_1^2+c_2^2+c_3^2}$$

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. But how to prove that vector inequality when the dimension goes beyond 3? I am really asking how to prove it using vigorous algebra. Thank you.

Comment: @IncredibleSimon Generally modulus of sum is less than sum of moduli. In general whether they are real numbers, complex numbers or vectors. Also do remember that you wanted to solve a problem.

Comment: @IncredibleSimon triangle inequality is rigorous in each inner product space, like $\mathbb{R}^n$. Moreover, here the dimension does not go beyond $3$.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself. My question should indeed be how to prove the triangle inequality in terms of vectors in general.

Let **a** and **b** be vectors of any dimension >= 1. To prove |**a**+**b**| <= |**a**|^2 + |**b**|^2, we could square both sides and replace the resultant left-hand side by dot product, and we could do some expansion and cancellation to get 2|**a**||**b**|cos(theta) <= 2|**a**||**b**| which is obviously true.

Then it can be easily generalized to get the inequality in the question.

(*Note*: the modulus and dot product for vectors of dimension greater than 3 cannot be visually interpreted, so they are just defined similarly as for the lower dimensions.)